# Compile a C project to DLL file in windows

Tags: c, gcc, dll, compilation, mingw

I downloaded libnova library from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libnova/).

Following the README, I can create `.a` and `.so` libraries. But I need the `.dll` file for a Qt program on Windows. Can you tell me how to generate a `.dll` file ? I'm very familiar with Linux but a newbie regarding Windows.

Any reply is appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your post and include the tag for the compiler you are using. Otherwise it is impossible to answer the question.

Comment: Thanks. I use gcc in mingw

Comment: Googling "mingw build dll" may help. The first hit is [HOWTO Create and Deploy a Sample DLL using MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/sampledll)

Answer (score 0):

Use following command in console window:

```
 g++ -shared -o example_dll.dll example_dll.o -W
```

note: GCC need to be installed before do this.

Answer (score 0):

This Method is for Static Library [here](https://www.zealfortechnology.com/2013/08/create-c-program-static-library-command-line-windows.html)

Go and Refer [here](https://www.zealfortechnology.com/2013/08/create-c-program-dll-dynamic-link-library-command-line-windows.html)... this is for windows dynamic linking...

Thanks & Regards...